# Make redis client wait when server is running a long lua script

Tags: python, redis

I'm having a single redis server serve multiple clients. Sometimes server needs to run a lua script that takes around a minute to complete. However during that time other clients get response error:

> redis.exceptions.ResponseError: BUSY Redis is busy running a script. You can only call SCRIPT KILL or SHUTDOWN NOSAVE

Is there in built way to tell client to just keep waiting or retrying this response?
 `Redis(socket_timeout=9999)` doesn't seem to have an effect on this.

Comment: I would go opposite way - try with short timeout, and retry at your side... It allows you to have better control on timeouts. Also note that system can have settings that interfere with yours - at least that was the case under Linux some time ago...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a proper way to do so I went with a bit of a hack:

```
from redis import Redis

class MyRedis(Redis):
    lua_retry_time = 120

    # override execute to retry busy errors 
    def execute_command(self, *args, **options):
        wait_time = 0
        if not self.lua_retry_time:
            return super().execute_command(*args, **options)
        while wait_time < self.lua_retry_time:
            try:
                return super().execute_command(*args, **options)
            except ResponseError as e:
                if 'busy redis is busy' not in ''.join(e.args).lower():
                    raise e
                if wait_time == 0:  # only print once
                    print('Redis is busy, waiting up to 120 seconds...')
                time.sleep(2)
                wait_time += 2
        return super().execute_command(*args, **options)
```

Every command in `redis-py` package goes through `execute_command` method this this should cover everything. 
This will keep retrying for 120 seconds every 2 seconds.